# How to maintain a range definition in excel vba after underlying cell changes?

Tags: vba, excel, cell

Excel noob here (sorry).  My macro runs like this:

```
Dim CellA, CellB As Range
Range("A1") = 25
Set CellA = Range("A1")
Range("A1") = 50
Set CellB = Range("A1")
```

The problem is after this, `CellA` also will be equal to `50`.

Is it possible to adjust the code to keep `CellA` as `25` but still use A1 as the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's clearly not possible, I'll try to explain you why. 
In this piece of code, you are saying:

```
Dim CellA As Range '<-- CellA will be an object of type "Range"
Set CellA = Range("A1") '<-- CellA will point to the Range("A1")
```

This means that, no matter what, `CellA` will always be pointing to `Range("A1")`. So, when you change:

```
Range("A1") = 50 '<-- please note: when you write this, you're "implicitely" writing Range("A1").Value = 50. The ".Value" is in fact the default property of the range object (if you don't specify anything, you will set that one).
```

... the value of `CellA` will be the value of `Range("A1")`, which is *exactly* what you told it to be when saying `Set CellA = Range("A1")`.

If you want to store the *value* (and not the Range object, as you're doing now), and not the whole range object, then you should do this:

```
Dim CellA As Long
CellA = Range("A1").Value
```

Even if the value of `Range("A1")` will change later in run-time, the value of `CellA` will still be the old one.

And this is surely what you want to do, because you don't care about the whole range object but only about its value: do you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misstated.  Terrible, the two cells are supposed to be pointing to a formula.  I should have stated that Range("A") is supposed to equal B1-C1 or something, and then CellA is based off B1-C1.  This is why I have to use Set.

Comment: Actually, your solution is perfect!  Thank you.  The .value function is exactly what I needed.  Again, sorry for being an excel noob.

Comment: @Lionel you don't have to feel sorry, nobody knows things before to learn them.. good luck with your project and don't hesitate to ask on SO if you're stuck with a specific piece of code and your own researches did not yield the expected result!